# Blackboard bold like symbols for the number "one" 1 and its mirror shape

Tags: symbols

I am looking for latex codes for the following characters:

[image]

My attempt to use detexify to find the symbols were unsuccessful.

`\mathbb{1}` does not produce the right symbol.

Comment: @campa, the link you sent, solves the problem for 1, but not for its mirror.

Comment: Once you have the blackboard bold "1", you can use the `\reflectbox` command from the `graphicx` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm,graphicx}
\begin{document}
$\mathbbm{1}$\reflectbox{$\mathbbm{1}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, in campa's referenced answer, there is also the `dsfont` package, giving what looks like a scalable alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont,graphicx}
\begin{document}
$\mathds{1}$\reflectbox{$\mathds{1}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\reflectbox` is shorter `;-)`

Comment: @campa Thanks.  I approach LaTeX like I do physics.  I just remember the original equation, F=d(mv)/dt, and the rest proceeds from there.

Comment: Thank you, this correctly answers my question. The only problem is that I want to use the code for a review for zbmath. I am not sure if they accept graphicx and bbm packages. Let me wait a while before accepting the answer to increase the chance of having new answer. Eventually, I accept the current answer if no new answer comes.

Comment: @Name The `\reflectbox` is available in several packages, additionally, `mathtools`, and `rotating`, if that helps.

Comment: @Name If you are unable to use the `bbm` or `dsfont` packages, a cheap cheat for the digit `1` might be had with `$\scalebox{1}[.91]{$1$}\mkern-5.2mu\scalebox{.5}[1]{$1$}$` (feel free to adjust parameters).  This, however, still requires `graphicx`, `mathtools`, or `rotating` to accomplish.

Comment: Please don’t use `bbm`. It’s a font format from the ’80s designed to be rasterized at one fixed resolution and printed out on paper. But nobody does that any more, and it looks pixelated on screens. The answer that recommended it is nearly ten years old.